# Android Studio: MediaPlayer - Playing radio from URL (https://***.pls) in Androd 10 device - stays as "Buffering" and stop

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, buffering, internet-radio

I am (very) new in Android Studio and I started by adapting a code that I found for playing a radio streaming from an URL (https://***.pls), what is exactly what I want to do. Originally this code was intended for reproducing several radio stations, but I just use it for a single station (URL).

After modifying the "superficial" info (pictures, station name, ...), the application can correctly play the radio in a device with Android 5.1 and Android 8, but when I press the play button in a device with Android 10 it stays as "Buffering" and after around a minute it is stopped.

This application have few fucntions but all of them are working correctly: Play, pause, stop. With the only exception of the buffering issue as explained above.

I already tested the app in virtual and real devices by upload the app in Google play store, with the same results in Andorid 10 devices (virtual and real).

```
<!-- AndroidManifest.xml - Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

As I can see the app is using MediaPlayer for this action.

For lasts days I was looking all around on internet inseveral forums and supporting pages about a similar issue, however, I did not find anything and I do not have a clue about which can be the reason of the issue, I assume that should be related to any configuration not correctly set for recent version of Android (as Android 10) but not sure.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Best regards.
Jesus

file build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    //android.ndkVersion  "21.0.6113669"
    ndkVersion "21.3.6528147"
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myname.radio"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    //implementation files('libs/aacdecoder-android-0.6.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/aacdecoder-android-0.8.jar')
    implementation files('libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar')
}
```

Below the code of the file RadioService.java

```
package com.myname.radio;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.spoledge.aacdecoder.MultiPlayer;
import com.spoledge.aacdecoder.PlayerCallback;

public class RadioService extends Service implements OnErrorListener,
        OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnInfoListener {
    private static String app_name;
    private static String lastfm_api_key;

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private MultiPlayer multiPlayer; // For AAC

    private String[] station_names;
    private String[] station_urls;
    private String[] station_types;
    private int current_station_id = 0;
    private Bitmap albumCover = null;
    private String album = "";
    private String artist = "";
    private String track = "";
    private String pre_artist = "";
    private String pre_track = "";

    public static final String MODE_CREATED = "CREATED";
    public static final String MODE_DESTROYED = "DESTROYED";
    public static final String MODE_PREPARED = "PREPARED";
    public static final String MODE_STARTED = "STARTED";
    public static final String MODE_CONNECTING = "CONNECTING";
    public static final String MODE_START_PREPARING = "START_PREPARING";
    public static final String MODE_PLAYING = "PLAYING";
    public static final String MODE_PAUSED = "PAUSED";
    public static final String MODE_STOPPED = "STOPPED";
    public static final String MODE_COMPLETED = "COMPLETED";
    public static final String MODE_ERROR = "ERROR";
    public static final String MODE_BUFFERING_START = "BUFFERING_START";
    public static final String MODE_BUFFERING_END = "BUFFERING_END";
    public static final String MODE_METADATA_UPDATED = "METADATA_UPDATED";
    public static final String MODE_ALBUM_UPDATED = "ALBUM_UPDATED";

    private String STATUS_CONNECTING;
    private String STATUS_BUFFERING;
    private String STATUS_READY;
    private String STATUS_PLAYING;
    private String STATUS_PAUSED;
    private String STATUS_STOPPED;
    private String STATUS_ERROR;
    private String STATUS_NOCONNECTION;

    private String status;
    private boolean isPrepared = false;
    private boolean isPreparingStarted = false;
    private boolean isRadioPlaying = false;

    private int timeCounter = -1;
    private String playingTime;

    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private final IBinder binder = new RadioBinder();

    private static final String TYPE_AAC = "aac";
    private static final String TYPE_MP3 = "mp3";
    private static final int AAC_BUFFER_CAPACITY_MS = 5000;
    private static final int AAC_DECODER_CAPACITY_MS = 700;

    // Notification
    private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID = 12345;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder notifyBuilder;
    private NotificationManager notifyMgr = null;

    private RadioMetadata metadata;

    private Timer metadataTimer;
    private Timer playtimeTimer;
    private int[] multiUrlTrack;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> multiUrl;
    private PlsParser parser;

    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        /* Create MediaPlayer when it starts for first time */

        app_name = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
        lastfm_api_key = getResources().getString(R.string.lastfm_api_key);

        station_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.station_names);
        station_urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.station_urls);
        station_types = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.station_types);

        STATUS_CONNECTING = getResources()
                .getString(R.string.status_connecting);
        STATUS_BUFFERING = getResources().getString(R.string.status_buffering);
        STATUS_READY = getResources().getString(R.string.status_ready);
        STATUS_PLAYING = getResources().getString(R.string.status_playing);
        STATUS_PAUSED = getResources().getString(R.string.status_paused);
        STATUS_STOPPED = getResources().getString(R.string.status_stopped);
        STATUS_ERROR = getResources().getString(R.string.status_error);
        STATUS_NOCONNECTION = getResources().getString(
                R.string.status_noconnection);

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        current_station_id = preferences.getInt("current_station_id", 0);

        multiUrl = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        multiUrlTrack = new int[station_urls.length];

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < station_urls.length; i++) {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    multiUrlTrack[i] = 0;
                    /*
                     * if (station_urls[i].toLowerCase().contains(".pls") ||
                     * station_urls[i].toLowerCase().contains(".m3u") ||
                     * station_urls[i].toLowerCase().contains(".m3u8") ||
                     * station_urls[i].toLowerCase().contains(".xspf") ||
                     * station_urls[i].toLowerCase().contains(".txt")) { parser
                     * = new PlsParser(station_urls[i]); list =
                     * parser.getUrls(); if (list == null || list.size() == 0) {
                     * list = new ArrayList<String>();
                     * list.add(station_urls[i]); } } else { list = new
                     * ArrayList<String>(); list.add(station_urls[i]); }
                     * station_urls[i] = list.get(0);
                     */
                    multiUrl.add(list);
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();

        try {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
            multiPlayer = new MultiPlayer(multiPlayerCallback,
                    AAC_BUFFER_CAPACITY_MS, AAC_DECODER_CAPACITY_MS);
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_CREATED));

        notifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // showNotification();

        metadata = new RadioMetadata();

        startRefreshingMetadata();
        startPlayTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        clearServiceData();
        // sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_DESTROYED));
    }

    public void clearServiceData() {
        timeCounter = -1;
        stop();
        resetMetadata();
        isPrepared = false;
        exitNotification();
        stopRefreshingMetadata();
        stopPlayTimer();

        current_station_id = preferences.getInt("current_station_id", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // showNotification();
        if (isPlaying())
            setStatus(STATUS_PLAYING);
        else if (isPreparingStarted()) {
            setStatus(STATUS_BUFFERING);
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_START_PREPARING));
        } else {
            setStatus("");
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STARTED));
        }

        /* Starts playback at first time or resumes if it is restarted */
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PLAYING));
        else if (isPrepared) {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PAUSED));
        }

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer _mediaPlayer) {
        /* If radio is prepared then start playback */
        setStatus("");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PREPARED));
        isPrepared = true;
        isPreparingStarted = false;
        timeCounter = 0;
        play();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        /* When no stream found then complete the playback */
        isRadioPlaying = false;
        timeCounter = -1;
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        resetMetadata();
        isPrepared = false;
        setStatus(STATUS_STOPPED);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_COMPLETED));

        setCurrentStationURL2nextSlot();
    }

    public void prepare() {
        /* Prepare Async Task - starts buffering */
        isPreparingStarted = true;

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (getCurrentStationURL().toLowerCase().contains(".pls")
                        || getCurrentStationURL().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(".m3u")
                        || getCurrentStationURL().toLowerCase().contains(
                                ".m3u8")
                        || getCurrentStationURL().toLowerCase().contains(
                                ".xspf")
                        || getCurrentStationURL().toLowerCase()
                                .contains(".txt")) {

                    setStatus(STATUS_CONNECTING);
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_CONNECTING));
                    showNotification();

                    parser = new PlsParser(getCurrentStationURL());
                    ArrayList<String> list = parser.getUrls();
                    if (list == null || list.size() == 0) {
                        System.out.println("Playlist: No file found");
                        stop();
                        return;
                    } else {
                        station_urls[getCurrentStationID()] = list
                                .get(multiUrlTrack[getCurrentStationID()]);
                        multiUrl.set(getCurrentStationID(), list);
                        System.out.println("Playlist: Selected url - "
                                + station_urls[getCurrentStationID()]);

                        // multiUrlTrack[getCurrentStationID()] = 1;
                    }
                }

                setStatus(STATUS_BUFFERING);
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_START_PREPARING));
                showNotification();
                try {
                    if (getCurrentStationType().equals(TYPE_AAC))
                        multiPlayer.playAsync(getCurrentStationURL());
                    else {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getCurrentStationURL());
                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                    }
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    stop();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    stop();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    stop();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    stop();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    stop();
                }

            }
        });

        thread.start();
    }

    public boolean isPlaying() {
        if (getCurrentStationType().equals(TYPE_AAC))
            return isRadioPlaying;
        else
            return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    public boolean isPreparingStarted() {
        return isPreparingStarted;
    }

    public void play() {
        if (hasConnectivity()) {
            if (getCurrentStationType().equals(TYPE_AAC)) {
                prepare();
            } else {
                if (isPrepared) {
                    isRadioPlaying = true;
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    System.out.println("RadioService: play");
                    setStatus(STATUS_PLAYING);
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PLAYING));
                } else {
                    prepare();
                }
            }
        } else
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STOPPED));

    }

    public void pause() {
        if (!getCurrentStationType().equals(TYPE_AAC)) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            isRadioPlaying = false;
            System.out.println("RadioService: pause");
            setStatus(STATUS_PAUSED);
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PAUSED));
        }
    }

    public void stop() {

        timeCounter = -1;
        resetMetadata();
        isPrepared = false;
        isPreparingStarted = false;
        System.out.println("RadioService: stop");

        if (getCurrentStationType().equals(TYPE_AAC)) {
            if (isRadioPlaying) {
                isRadioPlaying = false;
                multiPlayer.stop();
            }
            // else
            // sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STOPPED));
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.reset();

            isRadioPlaying = false;
            setStatus("");
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STOPPED));
        }
        // clearNotification();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        /* Check when buffering is started or ended */
        //
        if (what == 701) { // MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START
            isRadioPlaying = false;
            setStatus(STATUS_BUFFERING);
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_BUFFERING_START));
        } else if (what == 702) { // MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END
            isRadioPlaying = true;
            setStatus(STATUS_PLAYING);
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_BUFFERING_END));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        isRadioPlaying = false;
        timeCounter = -1;

        stop();

        switch (what) {
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
            Log.v("ERROR", "MEDIA ERROR NOT VALID FOR PROGRESSIVE PLAYBACK "
                    + extra);
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
            Log.v("ERROR", "MEDIA ERROR SERVER DIED " + extra);
            break;
        case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
            Log.v("ERROR", "MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN " + extra);
            break;
        }

        setStatus(STATUS_ERROR);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_ERROR));

        return false;
    }

    public int getCurrentStationID() {
        return current_station_id;
    }

    public void setCurrentStationID(int id) {
        resetMetadata();
        current_station_id = id;
        Editor edit = preferences.edit();
        edit.putInt("current_station_id", id);
        edit.commit();
        updateMetadataURL();
    }

    public String getCurrentStationName() {
        return station_names[current_station_id];
    }

    public String getCurrentStationURL() {
        String url = null;
        try {
            url = station_urls[current_station_id];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            setCurrentStationID(0);
            url = station_urls[current_station_id];
        }
        return url;
    }

    public String getCurrentStationType() {
        if (station_types[current_station_id].toLowerCase().trim()
                .equals("aac")
                || station_types[current_station_id].toLowerCase().trim()
                        .equals("aac+"))
            return TYPE_AAC;
        else
            return TYPE_MP3;
    }

    public void setCurrentStationURL2nextSlot() {
        try {
            if (multiUrlTrack[current_station_id] >= multiUrl.get(
                    current_station_id).size()) {
                multiUrlTrack[current_station_id] = 0;
            } else {

                Log.d("PlsParser", "Setting next stream from playlist: "
                        + multiUrlTrack[current_station_id]);

                Log.d("PlsParser",
                        "URL = "
                                + multiUrl.get(current_station_id).get(
                                        multiUrlTrack[current_station_id]));

                station_urls[current_station_id] = multiUrl.get(
                        current_station_id).get(
                        multiUrlTrack[current_station_id]);
                multiUrlTrack[current_station_id]++;

                play();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int getTotalStationNumber() {
        return station_urls.length;
    }

    public Bitmap getAlbumCover() {
        return albumCover;
    }

    public String getAlbum() {
        return album;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public String getTrack() {
        return track;
    }

    public String getPlayingTime() {
        if (timeCounter < 0) {
            playingTime = "";
            return "";
        } else
            return playingTime;
    }

    public void setAlbum(String str) {
        album = str;
    }

    public void setArtist(String str) {
        artist = str;
    }

    public void setTrack(String str) {
        track = str;
    }

    public void setNextStation() {
        resetMetadata();

        if (current_station_id == getTotalStationNumber() - 1)
            setCurrentStationID(0); // current_station_id = 0;
        else
            setCurrentStationID(getCurrentStationID() + 1); // current_station_id
                                                            // += 1;

        updateMetadataURL();
    }

    public void setPreviousStation() {
        resetMetadata();

        if (current_station_id == 0)
            setCurrentStationID(getTotalStationNumber() - 1);// current_station_id
                                                                // =
                                                                // getTotalStationNumber()
                                                                // - 1;
        else
            setCurrentStationID(getCurrentStationID() - 1); // current_station_id
                                                            // -= 1;

        updateMetadataURL();
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        if (!hasConnectivity())
            this.status = STATUS_NOCONNECTION;

        updateNotification(this.status);
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        if (!hasConnectivity())
            this.status = STATUS_NOCONNECTION;
        else
            this.status = status;

        updateNotification(this.status);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return binder;
    }

    /* Allowing activity to access all methods of RadioService */
    public class RadioBinder extends Binder {
        RadioService getService() {
            return RadioService.this;
        }
    }

    public void showNotification() {
        notifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(app_name)
                .setContentText("");
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        notifyMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifyMgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, notifyBuilder.build());
    }

    public void clearNotification() {
        if (notifyMgr != null)
            notifyMgr.cancel(NOTIFY_ME_ID);
    }

    public void exitNotification() {
        clearNotification();
        notifyBuilder = null;
        notifyMgr = null;
    }

    public void updateNotification(String status) {
        try {
            if (getTotalStationNumber() > 1) {
                if (status != "")
                    status = getCurrentStationName() + " - " + status;
                else
                    status = getCurrentStationName();
            }

            if (notifyBuilder != null && notifyMgr != null) {
                notifyBuilder.setContentText(status).setWhen(0);
                notifyMgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, notifyBuilder.build());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean hasConnectivity() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected class MetadataTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, RadioMetadata> {
        private URL stream_url;

        @Override
        protected RadioMetadata doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            try {
                stream_url = urls[0];
                metadata.refreshMeta();
                Log.e("Retrieving MetaData", stream_url.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Log.e(MetadataTask.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
                resetMetadata();
            }
            return metadata;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(RadioMetadata result) {
            try {
                // String title_artist=metadata.getStreamTitle();
                String meta_artist = metadata.getArtist();
                String meta_track = metadata.getTitle();

                if (stream_url.toString().equals(getCurrentStationURL())) {
                    updateMetadataTitle(meta_artist, meta_track);
                }
                // metaFlag=true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(MetadataTask.class.toString(), e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateMetadataTitle(String meta_artist, String meta_track) {

        if (meta_track != null) {
            artist = meta_artist;
            track = meta_track;

            if (artist.equals(pre_artist) && track.equals(pre_track)) {
            } else {
                pre_artist = artist;
                pre_track = track;
                clearAlbum();
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_METADATA_UPDATED));
                System.out.println(artist);
                System.out.println(track);

                updateAlbum();
            }
        } else
            clearAlbum();

    }

    public void startRefreshingMetadata() {
        updateMetadataURL();

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        metadataTimer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            if (getCurrentStationType().equals(TYPE_MP3)
                                    && (isPlaying() || isPreparingStarted)) {
                                MetadataTask performBackgroundTask = new MetadataTask();
                                performBackgroundTask.execute(new URL(
                                        getCurrentStationURL()));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // Log.e(MetadataTask.class.toString(),
                            // e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        metadataTimer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000);
    }

    public void stopRefreshingMetadata() {
        metadataTimer.cancel();
    }

    public void updateMetadataURL() {
        try {
            resetMetadata();
            if (getCurrentStationURL() != null)
                metadata.setStreamUrl(new URL(getCurrentStationURL()));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void resetMetadata() {
        artist = "";
        track = "";
        pre_artist = "";
        pre_track = "";
        clearAlbum();
    }

    /* Update Album */
    public void clearAlbum() {
        album = "";
        albumCover = null;
    }

    public void updateAlbum() {
        try {
            String musicInfo[] = { getArtist(), getTrack() };

            if (!musicInfo[0].equals("") && !musicInfo[1].equals(""))
                new LastFMCoverAsyncTask().execute(musicInfo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class LastFMCoverAsyncTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                bmp = LastFMCover.getCoverImageFromTrack(lastfm_api_key,
                        params[0], params[1]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return bmp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
            albumCover = bmp;
            if (bmp != null)
                album = LastFMCover.album;
            else
                album = "";
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_ALBUM_UPDATED));
            System.out.println(album);
            System.out.println(albumCover);
        }
    }

    /* Play Timer */
    public void startPlayTimer() {
        playtimeTimer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isRadioPlaying == true) {
                    timeCounter++;
                    int seconds = timeCounter;
                    int minutes = seconds / 60;
                    int hours = minutes / 60;
                    seconds = seconds % 60;
                    minutes = minutes % 60;
                    if (hours > 0)
                        playingTime = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours,
                                minutes, seconds);
                    else
                        playingTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes,
                                seconds);
                }
            }
        };
        playtimeTimer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000);
    }

    public void stopPlayTimer() {
        playtimeTimer.cancel();
    }

    /* ----------------- AAC Player ------------------------ */
    public final PlayerCallback multiPlayerCallback = new PlayerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void playerStarted() {
            timeCounter = 0;
            // isRadioPlaying =
            // true;
            // System.out.println("RadioService: play");
            // setStatus(STATUS_PLAYING);
            // sendBroadcast(new
            // Intent(MODE_PLAYING));
        }

        @Override
        public void playerPCMFeedBuffer(boolean isPlaying, int bufSizeMs,
                int bufCapacityMs) {

            float percent = bufSizeMs * 100 / bufCapacityMs;
            System.out.println("Buffer = " + percent + "% , " + bufSizeMs
                    + " / " + bufCapacityMs);

            if (isPlaying == true) {
                isPrepared = true;
                isPreparingStarted = false;

                if (bufSizeMs < 500) {
                    isRadioPlaying = false;
                    setStatus(STATUS_BUFFERING);
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_BUFFERING_START));
                } else {
                    isRadioPlaying = true;
                    setStatus(STATUS_PLAYING);
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_PLAYING));
                }
            } else {
                isRadioPlaying = false;
                setStatus(STATUS_BUFFERING);
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_BUFFERING_START));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void playerStopped(int perf) {

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timeCounter = -1;
                    playingTime = "";

                    isRadioPlaying = false;
                    isPreparingStarted = false;
                    System.out.println("RadioService: stop");
                    setStatus("");
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_STOPPED));
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void playerException(Throwable t) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    isRadioPlaying = false;
                    isPreparingStarted = false;
                    playingTime = "";
                    timeCounter = -1;
                    System.out.println("RadioService: Error Playing Stream");
                    setStatus(STATUS_ERROR);
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(MODE_ERROR));
                    
                    setCurrentStationURL2nextSlot();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void playerMetadata(String key, String value) {
            System.out.println("Metadata--------------");
            System.out.println(key + " ==> " + value);

            if ("StreamTitle".equals(key) || "icy-name".equals(key)
                    || "icy-description".equals(key)) {
                final String meta_artist = getArtistFromAAC(value);
                final String meta_track = getTrackFromAAC(value);

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateMetadataTitle(meta_artist, meta_track);
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void playerAudioTrackCreated(AudioTrack audioTrack) {

        }
    };

    private String getArtistFromAAC(String streamTitle) {
        int end = streamTitle.indexOf("-");
        if (end <= 0)
            end = streamTitle.indexOf(":");

        String title;
        if (end > 0)
            title = streamTitle.substring(0, end);
        else
            title = streamTitle;
        return title.trim();
    }

    private String getTrackFromAAC(String streamTitle) {
        int start = streamTitle.indexOf("-") + 1;
        if (start <= 0)
            start = streamTitle.indexOf(":") + 1;

        String track;
        if (start > 0)
            track = streamTitle.substring(start);
        else
            track = streamTitle;

        int end = streamTitle.indexOf("(");
        if (end > 0)
            track = streamTitle.substring(start, end);

        end = streamTitle.indexOf("[");
        if (end > 0)
            track = streamTitle.substring(start, end);

        return track.trim();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the menifest code and place where you are starting the service(RadioService). Means the code where you click on play and pause

Comment: Hi Abdul; thanks for your comment.

Comment: Abdul, here you can check the file Manifest and others.  Is this what you want to see?
https://jesedugal.stackstorage.com/s/47FJj8ZhCkKxvcKU
https://jesedugal.stackstorage.com/s/Dqq7Tb2ktpcPfta4